# Locking a column in an access table (Access 2013)

Tags: ms-access, vba

I was wondering how i would be able to lock a column in Microsoft access so it wouldn't be editable in the table. This column would auto fill by a script I have written. From what I've researched this is only possible in forms. I do not want to lock the whole table, just one column.

Thank you

Comment: I am 99% sure that can't be done, except for an Autonumber field (which does so by default).

Comment: If a column is to be 'calculated' it is usually considered good practice to NOT populate. Calculate the value in a query and use the query wherever you would have used the table. Also, how would someone edit the column? Users should not have access to tables directly, only forms. As you noted, it can easily be made non-editable in a form.

Comment: Has this changed since 2015 when this question was originally asked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't do it. The Access security model does not support attribute-level security.

You could create a separate table that is not editable by your user, then link that table to the editable table with a foreign key.